# where is bidirectional ? grails one-to-one, testing bidirectional (continue)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Book {

  String title
  Date releaseDate
  String ISBN

  static belongsTo = [person:Person]  // it makes relationship bi-directional regarding the grails-docs
}
```

```
class Person {

  Book book;  // it will create person.book_id

  String name
  Integer age
  Date lastVisit

  static constraints = {
    book unique: true  // "one-to-one". Without that = "Many-to-one".
  }

}
```

There is a test which test if it is real bidirectional or not. As i understand it.

```
  public void testBidirectional() {
    def person = new Person(name:"person_c1", age: 99, lastVisit: new Date())

     def book = new Book(
             title:"somebook_c1",
             ISBN: "somebook_c1",
             releaseDate: new Date()
     )

     person.setBook (book)

     assertNotNull(person.save())

     def bookId = person.getBook().id

     Book thatBook = Book.get(bookId)
     assertNotNull(thatBook.person) // NULL !!!
  }
```

So, i save a **person** with a **book**, and then i got that **book** from db by id. Then from that **book** i try to get back the **person** which book should refer to (because it should be bidirectional, right?). Eventually i got **null** instead of an instance of the **person**.

The questing is: ***how to make that test working?***

Answer (score 1):

i have found the solution how to get it working, but still can not understand why it does not work without 'refresh', see below:

```
public void testBidirectional() {
     def person = new Person(name:"person_c1", age: 99, lastVisit: new Date())

     def book = new Book(
             title:"somebook_c1",
             ISBN: "somebook_c1",
             releaseDate: new Date()
     )

     person.setBook (book)

     def p = person.save()

     assertNotNull p

     person.refresh() //load the object again from the database so all the changes made to object will be reverted
     //person = Person.get(p.id)   // BUT this also gets the object from db ...?

     def bookId = person.getBook().id
     assertNotNull bookId

     def thatBook = Book.get(bookId)
     assertNotNull(thatBook.person)
  }
```

So, here as you can see i use 'refresh' to  get it working, but why it does not work without 'refresh' but with the following line after 'refresh' - this one: 
 `person = Person.get(p.id)   // BUT this also gets the object from db ...?`

If i just want to  **get** object from database by id, then it would be without bidirectional?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably caused by the way that Hibernate works. Grails used Hibernate under the hood.

**Even when you call "save", the object *person* may (and usually) not saved in database.** That's because Hibernate is programmed to optimize the query, so it often waits to perform all query at then end of the Hibernate session.

That means if you don't call "refresh", the book-person relation (person.setBook) is still in memory, but not saved in database. Hence you can't get the `book.person` from `book`.

To enforce the save, you can use "refresh" like the previous answer, or use flush:true.

I still not try, but it's very likely that you will produce desired results with:

```
person.save(flush:true)
```